# Why a subquery accept column name from main query

Tags: sql

Consider these 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE maintable (
  a_main varchar,
  b_main varchar
);
  
CREATE TABLE sub_table (
  a_sub varchar,
  b_sub varchar
);
```

I do not understand why this query has no error : a_main do not belong to sub_table. And what is the meaning of such a subquery ?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    maintable
WHERE
    a_main IN
      (
        SELECT
           a_main
        FROM
          sub_table
      )
```

Comment: Are you sure this query runs without an error? I don't see how it can, for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: @O.Jones, the query runs smoothly https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2022/c1954a7818e1f2797cac72ec3b8d78b6/

Comment: This is why you should always _qualify_ all columns! E.g. `sub_table.a_main` instead of just `a_main`.

Answer (score 2):

On its own, the query

```
select a_main
from sub_table
```

will naturally fail for the reason stated, the column does not exist.

However, you are using this query as a sub-query, and a sub query can be *correlated* with the outer query.

You are not referencing a table by its name or alias specifically, so for your example, the query optimizer checks *both* the inner and outer queries to resolve the column reference.

Your query is *equivalent* to:

```
select *
from maintable mt
where mt.a_main in (
    select mt.a_main
    from sub_table st
);
```

However if you write it with how you are *assuming* it gets executed then it will fail:

```
select *
from maintable mt
where mt.a_main in (
    select st.a_main
    from sub_table st
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How works this query? It scan the `maintable` and for each row checks is the value of `a_main` of row contained by your subquery results. So the query will  returns all rows from `maintable` when `sub_table` contains at least one row.
Test it [here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2022/ae84effc3a54217a3a5c469da0001844/)

When you need to filter `maintable` by `sub_table` you should to use next query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    maintable
WHERE
    a_main IN
      (
        SELECT
           a_sub
        FROM
          sub_table
      )
```

https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2022/26c210f5bd249de050abf395cd183663/